# CCLabelTTF value is not updating (cocos2d)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i have two layers control layer which contains CCLabelTTF for score, and first layer in which i detect collision btwn my objects. i want to update score (i.e CCLabelTTF value) in control layer from my first layer.

here is my code...

my scene.m

```
-(id)init{

    self=[super init];   

    FirstLayer *fl=[FirstLayer node];

    [self addChild:fl];

    controlLayer *cl=[controlLayer node];

    [self addChild:cl z:3 tag:1];

    return self;


       }
```

control layer.h

```
@interface controlLayer : CCLayer{
     CCLabelTTF * score ;
     int score_value;        
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)CCLabelTTF * score ;
@property int score_value;

-(void)displayScore;    
@end
```

controlLayer.m

```
-(id)init{        
   // my code..            
        [self displayScore];            
    }

    return self;
}


-(void)displayScore{        
    CGSize screenSize=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize];    
    CCLabelTTF * score_lbl = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Score" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:16.0];    
    score_lbl.position=ccp(screenSize.width*0.10,screenSize.height*0.90);        
    [self addChild:score_lbl z:99];

    score =[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test:%d",score_value] fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:16.0] ;          
    NSString *str = [score string];        
    NSLog(@"SCORE control:%@",str);    
    score.position=ccp(screenSize.width*0.20,screenSize.height*0.90);        
    [self addChild:score];        
}
```

firstLayer.h

```
@interface FirstLayer : CCLayer     
{           
    controlLayer *cl;                
    }

@property(nonatomic,retain)controlLayer *cl;    

@end
```

firstLayer.m

```
@implementation FirstLayer

@synthesize cl;    
    -(id)init{

 ---

cl=[controlLayer new];
[self schedule:@selector(tick:)];

    return self;

}


-(void)tick:(ccTime)dt{           
    bool blockFound=false;        
    world->Step(dt, 10, 10);      

    std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
    for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin(); 
        pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) {
        MyContact contact = *pos;          

        b2Body *bodyA = contact.fixtureA->GetBody();
        b2Body *bodyB = contact.fixtureB->GetBody();
        if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL) {
            CCSprite *spriteA = (CCSprite *) bodyA->GetUserData();
            CCSprite *spriteB = (CCSprite *) bodyB->GetUserData();                         

            // Sprite A = ball, Sprite B = Block
            if (spriteA.tag == 1 && spriteB.tag == 2) {                    

                cl.score_value=cl.score_value+5;

                [cl.score setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cl.score_value]];                                   

                NSString *str = [cl.score string];

                NSLog(@"SCORE in GAME:%@",str);

               // [cl displayScore];                        

                if (std::find(toDestroy.begin(), toDestroy.end(), bodyB) 
                    == toDestroy.end()) {
                    toDestroy.push_back(bodyB);

                }
            }
            // Sprite B = block, Sprite A = ball
            else if (spriteA.tag == 2 && spriteB.tag == 1) {                      

                cl.score_value=cl.score_value+5;

               [cl.score setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cl.score_value]];

                NSString *str = [cl.score string];

                NSLog(@"SCORE in GAME:%@",str);

             //    [cl displayScore];                    

            }               

        }                 
    }
```

What is going Wrong? , i'm always getting score:test 0 !:(

Comment: can you see the output of `NSLog(@"SCORE control:%@",str);`?

Comment: What about score_value? Does it represent correct score?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha: yes in my firstLayer im getting correct value of score_value.

Comment: @Sergio: NSLog(@"SCORE control:%@",str); is 0, but i think it is not called after i have set new score value in firstLayer...
[cl.score setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cl.score_value]];

Comment: Do you call displayScore method once only when creating an instance of  controlLayer?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha: yes, and i have taken my score label as property so that  i can update its value from my controlLayer.

Comment: Your issue is really weird. Are you sure the code inside of if (spriteA.tag == 1 && spriteB.tag == 2) and else if(spriteA.tag == 2 && spriteB.tag == 1) gets executed at all?

Comment: Where is the code that adds your controlLayer to the scene?  I'm concerned about your line `cl = [controlLayer new];`.  I don't think you are getting the right reference to the control layer.  Do you have a CCScene that is a parent of the controlLayer and the FirstLayer?  If so, then you need to get a reference to the controlLayer that was added to the CCScene: `cl = [gameScene getChildByTag:clTag]` or `cl = [self.parent getChildByTag:clTag]` or something similar.  In your CCScene you should initalize the layer like: `controllLayer *cl = [controlLayer node]; [self addChild:cl tag:clTag];`

Comment: obviously it is working, as my NSLog(@"SCORE in GAME:%@",str); is working between them!

Comment: @Sylvan: i'v added my scene code...can u tell me exactly how to get reference to my controlLayer...i tried this
cl = [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]runningScene] getChildByTag:1];
which is not working, i guess some conversion is needed :

Comment: Ok. In FirstLayer.m, get your controlLayer reference using `cl = (controlLayer*)[self.parent getChildByTag:1];`. Then you should be updating the score of the layer that is actually added to the scene. See if that works.

Comment: as Sylvian said, you did not add your control layer to any parent. so it simply does not drawn. but object is created, so you can get access to it's properties and print them using NSLog

Comment: In your FirstLayer.m, try implement `-(void)onEnter { [super onEnter]; cl = (controlLayer*)[self.parent getChildByTag:1]; }`  Instead of doing that call in the `init` method.

Comment: i'v tried cl = (controlLayer*)[self.parent getChildByTag:1]; , but in this case score_value not updating even in firstLayer. in output...SCORE in GAME:(null)

Comment: finally it works...cheers man! , -(void)onEnter did the trick, but what is exactly happend btwn init and onEnter!?

Comment: The `self.parent` might not be initialized until after init is done.  `-(void) onEnter {}` is called after initalization is complete. Glad it's working :)  I'll write up an answer to clarify all.

Comment: i'v another problem in this, im trying to update score on contact of two objects but my  [cl.score setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cl.score_value]]; is executed multiple time on one collision! , so user gets double/triple score on single shot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement `cl=[controlLayer new];` is not getting the reference of the controlLayer that was added to your game scene. As your game scene.m code indicates, both FirstLayer and controlLayer instances are initalized and added as children to the CCScene.  To get a proper reference to your controlLayer from inside FirstLayer, do it like this:

```
FirstLayer.m

-(void) onEnter {
[super onEnter];
cl = (controlLayer*)[self.parent getChildByTag:1];
}
```

The reason you have to put this in onEnter is because `self.parent` will not be valid within the FirstLayer's init method.  `onEnter` is called after initialization is complete. This should give you the reference to the actual controlLayer that was added to your game scene.

Answer (score -1):

I think by the looks of it, you are sending a new score value to your control layer, but you are not updating the label, as you only set it once. It won't automatically update if score_value changes. I think you need to schedule an update method in your control layer that will update the score label.

Comment: he calls setString method. isn't that enough to update the label?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha: right, i used setString for that purpose, and if i try to update my label by [self addChile:score]; it ll be crashed as already added child can not be re added.